# How can I replace/change/overwrite the selected visual block from default register in vim?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

Is it possible *replace/change* text selected via visual block with text held in the register?

---

Edit:
The normal <kbd>p</kbd> on top of the selected text does not work on my vim:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Nov  3 2021 04:38:26)
macOS version
```

---

Example: select the first 2 lines of column 3 (marked with `|-|`) in file1 with visual block mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>). Then *replace/change* them with text from default register previously yanked from column 3 in file2 (across first 2 lines) **without previously deleting** the block to be replaced?

I have to do this repeatedly between two files but only on certain lines from certain columns.

file1

```
              |-|
1 aaa     &   bbb -
2 aaa     &   bbb -
3 aaa     &   zzz
4 aaa     &   zzz
5 aaa     &   bbb
6 aaa     &   bbb
```

file2

```
              |-|
1 aaa     &   ccc -
2 aaa     &   ccc -
3 aaa     &   zzz
4 aaa     &   zzz
5 aaa     &   ccc
6 aaa     &   ccc
```

desired change in file1

```
1 aaa     &   ccc
2 aaa     &   ccc
3 aaa     &   zzz
4 aaa     &   zzz
5 aaa     &   bbb
6 aaa     &   bbb
```

So far did this:
I select the desired columns and lines via visual block and delete them in file1. Then, I switch tab to yank the needed columns (file2), switch back to file1, again and select the desired position and paste the text <kbd>p</kbd>.

I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do this. My ideal way would be: I go to file2 yank the needed columns and lines. Switch tab to file1 and select the text to be replaced via visual block mode. Then I simply use something like `r+p` or `c+p` to replace the selected text with the text from default register.

Another option I found is from this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26654/how-can-i-paste-overwriting-with-vim/26716#26716 using the following steps

1. Yank desired block of lines to be pasted
2. Move to the other tab and select text to be replaced delete using `d`. The register `"` holds now the deleted line, but register `0` still holds the previously yanked line.
3. Paste from `0` register using `"0P`

But this still forces me to delete the undesired text first.

Comment: I assume it is a duplicate, but I didn't find the right answer on SO. And I've spent 2 hrs on this reviewing other Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the selected lines in column 3 is **not** necessary.

Try this:

0. Open file1 in vim then open file2 by typing `:tabe file2`
1. In file2: Select the lines you want to yank in visual block mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> use <kbd>y</kbd> to yank the selected lines).

   [image]

   Switch tabs using <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>
2. In file1: Select lines to be replaced in visual block mode.

   [image]
3. Replace the lines from default register using <kbd>p</kbd>

   [image]

---

Due to some configuration issue <kbd>p</kbd> was not working for me initially and this answer instead had <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> in step 3 which worked for me. Using `vim -Nu NONE` to avoid loading my custom `.vimrc` I was able to use just <kbd>p</kbd>. Credit to [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) for helping to find the issue.